# change font size with jQuery when text is too long

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, font-size

on a wordpress theme i am trying to make i have some what narrow spaces for the post titles.
Normally it is ok when the words aren't too big (because a word can always go to the next line), but when there is a very long word (like "ANTIDISESTABLISHMENTARIANISM") then it is a problem.

I thought a solution could be to check with jQuery if on the title there is any word with more than x characters. i wanted to start be trying the total amount of characters in the title (vs. looking for long single words in side the title).

My code looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    var $title = $(".entry-title a").text();
    var $titlesize = $title.lenght();

    if ($titlesize > 10){
        $(title).css("color","red");
    }
});
```

(on this example i try to change the text color, so it is easy to see if it working or not...  ;)   ).

Any ideas on i could solve this? Would something like this affect ALL of the post titles or just the one which is too big?

Comment: Typo: `length` and it is a property not a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use CSS to handle this? Use the [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property.

Ex: `word-break: break-all;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7JLGq/)**

Comment: ai, ai, ai...   that is a really simple and nice solution. I just didn't know it existed! Thank you!  =)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with CSS3: `text-overflow: ellipsis`

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7JLGq/1/)**